# How to treat numbers starting with zeroes as decimal integer

Tags: shell, shell-script, arithmetic

Input would be file name like following :

```
A-B-000001-C
A-B-000002-C
.....
.....
A-B-999999-C
```

All file should be sequential. I want to find missing sequential file names. For this I'm separating 6 digit sequence number using **awk**  and using **grep** with regular expression to check if the file is present in the directory.

```
`ls|grep "A-B-${sequencenumber}-.*"|wc -l`
```

but shell script is not treating number as decimal and if I force the number to be treated as decimal using **10#$sequencenumber** then its removing preceding zeroes which is necessary for searching the file.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: `comm -13 <(ls) <(seq -f 'A-B-%06g-C' 999999)` to find the missing ones. See also [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some shells such as bash in their arithmetic expressions treat numbers with leading zeros as octal. A trick to work around this is to manipulate only numbers with an extra nonzero leading digit, e.g. count from 1000001 to 1999999. To get the desired number with leading zeros, strip the leading 1 with a string operation.

```
n=1000001
while [ "$n" -le 1999999 ]; do
  digits=${n#1}
  set "A-B-$digits-."*
  if [ -e "$1" ] || [ -L "$1" ]; then
    echo "${digits}: $#"
  fi
  n=$((n+1))
done
```

This method is portable to all POSIX shells and avoids creating a subprocess for the computations, which can make it faster (but a million iterations is likely to be slow anyway, shells aren't the best at performance).

In the script above, instead of the complex and slow command involving `ls` and `wc` to count matching files, I use shell built-in constructs: `set "A-B-$digits-."*` sets the positional parameters to the list of matching files, and the following line prints the number of matches (`$#`) if there is at least one match (if there's no match then the pattern remains unchanged and so `[ -e "$1" ]` is `[ -e "A-B-$digits-.*" ]` which is false).

Comment: The Q used `.*` in a BRE (for grep without -E -P etc); as a shell glob that's `A-B-$digits-*`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `printf` utility for padding, e.g.,

```
$(ls|grep "A-B-$(printf '%06d' $sequencenumber)-.*"|wc -l)
```

Two points:

- while both `foo` and `$(foo)` are [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03), nested backtics tend to not be as portable
- the [`printf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) utility is useful for more than just padding.

Answer (score 2):

Using `wc -l` will not produce the right result if your files name contain newline.

With `bash` and `zsh`, you can use brace expansion:

```
for n in {000001..999999}; do
  f=A-B-$n-C
  [ -f "$f" ] || printf '%s missing\n' "$f"
done
```

`ksh93` with `braceexpand` option enable:

```
for n in {1..999999%06d}; do
  : the code above
done
```

In `ksh` and `zsh`, you can do:

```
typeset -Z6 i=1
max=999999
while [ "$i" -le "$max" ]; do
  f=A-B-$i-C
  [ -f "$f" ] || printf '%s missing\n' "$f"
  : "$((i+=1))"
done
```

POSIXly:

```
min=1
max=999999
while [ "$min" -le "$max" ]; do
  f=$(printf "A-B-%0${#max}d-C" "$min")
  [ -f "$f" ] || printf '%s missing\n' "$f"
  : "$((min+=1))"
done
```

Comment: ksh and zsh also have `typeset -Z6 i`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Thank for the information. Added it to the answer.

Comment: filenames containing newline are already wrong in the `grep` before you get to the `wc` -- but you can eliminate `|wc -l` by `grep -c`. With GNU you could do `find . -maxdepth 1 -print0 | grep -zc`. But I concur `[ -f` is just better _if_ the `C` is fixed which Q doesn't promise; Gilles has a more general method for this.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`, you can also do:

```
expected=( A-B-{000001..999999}-C )
  actual=( A-B-<->-C(N)    )
 missing=( ${expected:|actual}    )
if (( $#missing )) print -rlu2 - "$#missing files are missing:" ' - '$^missing
```

You can also list the unexpected ones such as those where the number is not  within the 1..999999 range or expressed with a number of digits other than 6:

```
unexpected=( ${actual:|expected} )
if (( $#unexpected )) print -rlu2 - "$#unexpected unexpected files:" ' - '$^unexpected
```

Answer (score 0):

Works with `awk` for me:

```bash
set x=`echo $< | awk '{printf "%d",$1}' ` ; echo $x
```

```bash
033      # this is what I entered
33       # this prints out
```